# Erro de if dentro de if

Tags: javascript, html, if, else

Estou com um problema, ao meu ver a logica esta correta, entretanto não esta funcionando, tenho um select que tem que ser verificado e caso seja selecionado determinada opção ele abre outro select, nesse outro select dependendo da informação selecionada ele valida se existe algo escrito no campo input, o erro está que ele não esta verificando se existe algo nesse input e parece que ele pula esse if e já vai para o else.

Segue o código que estou tentando:

```
var aoption = document.getElementById("options").value;
var aopcDemaisTemAniver = ['Aniversario de Nascimento', 'Aniversario de Namoro', 'Aniversario de Casamento', 'Aniversario de Mêsversario', 'Outras Opções'];
var aoptionAni = document.getElementById("options2").value;
var ademaisOpcSex = ['Aniversario de Nascimento', 'Aniversario de Mêsversario'];
var ainput6 = document.getElementById("IdadePeriodo3").val()== null;

if(aoption == 'Aniversario' && !aopcDemaisTemAniver.includes(aoptionAni)){
    swal({
      title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
      text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario selecionar qual o tipo de Aniversario.",
      button: "Continuar",
    });
    document.formMonteCaixa.options2[0].focus();


       }else if(aoption == 'Aniversario' && !aopcDemaisTemAniver.includes(aoptionAni) && !ademaisOpcSex.includes(aoptionAni) && ainput6.length<1){
      swal({
        title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
        text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario informar o Idade / Periodo.",
        button: "Continuar",
      });
      document.formMonteCaixa.IdadePeriodo3[0].focus();


  }else{
    alert(ainput6);
    document.getElementById('BlocoDeEnvioEmailPag').style.display = 'block';
  }


<select id="options" name="options"  class="cc-selector" onchange="optionCheck()">
        <option value="Selecione o Tema:" disabled selected>Selecione o Tema:</option>
        <option value="Aniversario">Aniversário</option>
        <option value="Pedido Casamento">Pedido Casamento</option>
        <option value="Gravidez">Gravidez</option>
        <option value="Nascimento">Nascimento</option>
        <option value="Dia das Mães / Pais">Dia das Mães / Pais</option>
        <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
      </select>
        <div id="hiddenDiv" class="Aniversario" style="display:none;">
            <select id="options2" name="options2" onchange="optionCheck()">
                <option value="Aniversario" disabled selected>Aniversário de:</option>
                <option value="Aniversario de Nascimento">Aniversário de Nascimento</option>
                <option value="Aniversario de Namoro">Aniversário de Namoro</option>
                <option value="Aniversario de Casamento">Aniversário de Casamento</option>
                <option value="Aniversario de Mêsversario">Aniversário de Mêsversario</option>
                <option value="Outras Opções">Outras Opções</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div id="hiddenDiv4_1" class="OpçõesAniversarioComSex cc-selector" style="display:none;">
        <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco6Col1 ModeloCaixaBloco6Col1K">
         <input type="text" id="IdadePeriodo3" name="IdadePeriodo3" placeholder="Idade / Periodo"  onblur="optionCheck(this);">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está na sintaxe desta linha:

```
var ainput6 = document.getElementById("IdadePeriodo3").val()== null;
```

O método `val()` é para pegar valor de objetos jQuery. No seu caso, para pegar o valor do objeto, teria que usar `value`:

```
var ainput6 = document.getElementById("IdadePeriodo3").value == null;
```

Também não use `null` para verificar se há valor no campo. Verifique desta forma, se está vazio:

```
var ainput6 = document.getElementById("IdadePeriodo3").value == "";
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, inseri isso e fiz uma pequena alteração no meu if e agr está funcionando, if caso alguem necessite ficou dessa forma: (aoption == 'Aniversario' && ademaisOpcSex.includes(aoptionAni) && ainput6 == true)

Comment: @dvd não sabia desse ícone ✔️, que legal :)

Comment: Ah sim, sobre os ícones, vc pode copiar do site https://getemoji.com/ e colar aqui rs 

Comment: @dvd vi agora, você esqueceu me mencionar, assim eu não recebo as notificações.

Comment: @dvd porque no modo desenvolvedor (F12) não consigo ver o código do ícone ? Somente aparece desenho. Que bizarro !!!

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Pois eh cara, eu tb não entendo muito disso não... parece uma imagem mas não é, é como se fosse algum caractere

Comment: @dvd acho que vou fazer essa pergunta aqui no stackoverflow

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Eu tb pensei em fazer uns dias atrás, mas deixei pra lá

Answer (score 2):

Pegue e coloque valores no input com **.value** ao invés de **.val()**
Tente `document.getElementById("elemento").value`

Comment: Já havia feito essa alteração antes direto no codigo, porém para colocar aqui minha duvida tinha utilizado o codigo antigo de um bloco de notas infelizmente, porém muito obrigado por comentar :D, alterei meu if tbm caso alguem necessite: (aoption == 'Aniversario' && ademaisOpcSex.includes(aoptionAni) && ainput6 == true)

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém necessite disso tbm ficou dessa forma:

```
var ainput6 = document.getElementById("IdadePeriodo4").value == "";

if(aoption == 'Aniversario' && ademaisOpcSex.includes(aoptionAni) && ainput6 == true){
```